# inner hashable class declaration fail

Tags: c++

I want to have an inner class inside of an outer class and have the outer class put that inner class into a hashtable.  What is the sane way of achieving this?
My attempt:

```
#include <unordered_set>

class Outer {
public:
  struct Inner {
    int x;
  };

  std::unordered_set<Outer::Inner> inners;
};

namespace std {
  template<> struct hash<Outer::Inner> {
    size_t operator()(const Outer::Inner& o) {
      return 42;
    }
  };
}

int main() {
  Outer outer;
  std::unordered_set<Outer::Inner> inners;
  return 0;
}
```

doesn't work because the std::hash specialization is not defined by the tie I try to declare the unordered_set field of class Outer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this counts as 'sane', but it's the first idea that came to my mind.

You could make a custom hash class that forwards `operator()` calls to a member function of the target object (`.hash()` in the implementation below).

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <unordered_set>

struct member_hash {
  template <typename T> std::size_t operator()(const T &o) const {
    return o.hash();
  }
};

class Outer {
public:
  struct Inner {
    int x;
    std::size_t hash() const {
      return 42;
    }
  };

  std::unordered_set<Outer::Inner, member_hash> inners;
};

int main() {
  Outer outer;
  std::unordered_set<Outer::Inner, member_hash> inners;
  return 0;
}
```

Also note that `operator()` of a hash class should be `const`, at least on my GCC it refuses to work otherwise.

Comment: I was mostly viewing this approach as not sane because the declaration of the set becomes so crappy, but then i realized that I can typdef it and gave up.